# Eclipse application is not launching correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, installation

#### I am going through the setup for the Eclipse application. When I start the app it has me pick a work-space path, then it "crashes". prompts me with window to check .log file

- I am attempting to get an environment up for java and the environment required is with Java, Eclipse, wildfly, and then a database.
- Though I can't seem to get the Eclipse launcher to open. I have tried the cmnd line '-clean' and deleting the cache in the p2 core folder etc... I took some screen shots on some errors I've been getting, has anyone else ran into this issue? or know of a link that I have been unsuccessful on finding?

Thank you.

[image: selecting my work-space]

[image: error window prompt after I select my work-station path]

[image: error path .log file]

[image: file structure (a)]

[image: file structure (b)]

[image: file structure (c)]

Comment: @JimGarrison version 9.0.1

Comment: Java 9 is not supported in Eclipse until 4.7.1a, and you are running 4.7.0.  You need to download the current version of Eclipse, 4.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse introduced Java 9 support with 4.7.1a.

You should download the most current Eclipse version (4.7.2) and use that with Java 9

Comment: I appreciate you help with this issue/question, your solution worked right away.

Answer (score 0):

download the latest version of eclipse, depending on the kind of package you are using like neon, oxygen.